# Scala, docker - how to set mainClass in multimodule application using sbt-native-packager?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have created a multimodule, `sbt` project in Scala. For now it is:

- main project (`main-service`) with `build.sbt` file
- http module with `Main` class

In my `sbt` file I have:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(http)
  .settings(
    dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:jre-alpine",
    name := "main-service",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

    )
  )
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
  .enablePlugins(AshScriptPlugin)

lazy val http = (project in file("http"))
  .settings(
    mainClass in Compile := Some("Main"),
    name := "main-http",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(    
    ))
```

As you can see, I want to run it with `docker`. Image of this project is created well, but when I made `docker run` then I got an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/opt/docker/bin/main-service\": stat /opt/docker/bin/main-service: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

I think the problem could be with `mainClass` line. I have my `Main` class in `main-http/src/main/scala` directory, but it looks like docker does not see it.

How should I move this `Main` class or change path to it and run it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the main class in `http` subproject, you need to move the plugins to this project too as following.

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(http)
  .settings(name := "main-service")

lazy val http = (project in file("http"))
  .settings(
    mainClass in Compile := Some("Main"),
    dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:jre-alpine",
    name := "main-http",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq()
  )
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
  .enablePlugins(AshScriptPlugin)
```

The plugins must be enabled at the project where the Main class is located.

To build a docker image, do

```
sbt http/docker:publishLocal
```

Comment: Yes! It is exactly what I needed. Thanks.